# Contact Form 7 - Replace database configured form template with a static file

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

**TL;DR - Is there a way CF7 can pull it's form markup and tags from a static file, instead of the database? So I can maintain that file in version control.**

We have a very complex form running under Contact Form 7. It has branching, logic and more, all handled by custom code using hooks and filters. However we still have to copy and paste the (thousands of lines) of code that describes this form into the "form editor" in the Wordpress admin panel if the form is changed. We would never edit it there though, it'd be impossible, and in fact we keep this form as a static file, so we can version it. So we rely on the fact that the form in the database matches this static file at all times.

It occured to me today - why not cut out the middle-man and simply have CF7 use markup from this file directly? It would be easier to maintain, and stop anyone accidentally damaging the form markup in the editor.

Is such a mechanism available? Many thanks.

I have discovered this: https://medium.com/@deyanyanakiev/embed-contact-form-7-in-your-custom-theme-9e038c494815 a technique to replace teh default form on installation, but as I understand it, that would be a one-off operation and would not allow for the form to be updated.

Comment: The best i can think of would be having a cron-job doing what you should do manually, or to say it better something that simply reads the content of your file and place it inside the database so CF7 is happy with that. It should be quite easy actually, since CF7 is nothing more then a custom post type that lives inside the wp_posts table. Like once in a day(or w/e fits your file edits)

Comment: @Diego That's a fascinating idea. We use Beanstalk to deploy code, so we could even have that trigger a webhook to make sure the form markup in the static file - the "source of truth" so to speak, is then inserted into the DB over the top of any existing form. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :D

Answer (score 1):

> We would never edit it there though, it'd be impossible,

quite, the CF7 plugin was never conceived for anything more complex than a contact form unfortunately.  You may want to play around with the [Smart Grid-layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) which was specifically designed for creating and maintaining complex forms.  It has a [modular functionality](https://youtu.be/vPc3M5Emro4) that allows you to build a form using sub-forms, making form maintenance much easier.

It also uses the excellent [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) editor as its code editor, much more powerful than the ridiculous textarea used in CF7 plugin.

> simply have CF7 use markup from this file directly?

yes, that the simplest way to solve your problem.  Hook the following CF7 filter,

```
add_filter('wpcf7_default_template', 'load_custom_form_template',10,2);
function load_custom_form_template($template, $prop){
    if($prop !== 'form') return $template;
    include( 'path-to-your-default-form.php');
    return $template;
}
```

Now, if you do use the Smart Grid extension which has the ability to load form specific js and css scripts (only on the pages where the form is loaded), then you can hook the following actions to add JavaScript template,

```
add_action('cf7sg_default_custom_js_template', 'use_js_script',10,1);
function use_js_script($cf7_key){
  include_once 'path-to-your-default-js';
}
```

and CSS stylesheet template,

```
add_action('cf7sg_default_custom_css_template', 'use_css_script',10,1);
function use_css_script($cf7_key){
  include_once 'path-to-your-default-css';
}
```